# How frequently does windows flush the write cache?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-cache

Assuming a file transfer completes, how long does it take until windows flushes the write cache?

For example I run a backup on a hard drive (with write caching enabled). Once the backup is complete I turn off the drive. Does the write cache get flushed immediately once disk i/o has finished or is there a waiting period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows flushes its internal file cache on an eight-second rotating window. That is, every second, one-eighth of the dirty pages in the cache are queued for writing. The actual writing may take longer. Also, other factors may cause the writes to be delayed.

The drive's own on-board cache, as well as Windows' cache, is guaranteed to be flushed when you go through the "safely disconnect" dialog. It won't tell you "safe to remove" until the writes are actually completed in Windows *and* the drive reports that the command to flush its internal buffers to the media has finished.

Comment: Can you please provide references for your answer? My understanding is that (quoting from Windows Internals) *"...once per second the cache manager's lazy write function executes on a system worker thread and queues **one-eighth** of the dirty pages in the system cache..."* Also there are plenty of scenarios where the flushing algorithm adapts to workload so it's not always possible to know for sure when *all* writes are flushed.

Comment: If _Windows Internals_ says it's one eighth, then it's one eighth. I have edited the above - thanks. The advice to go through the "safely disconnect" sequence is still correct; that _does_ tell you that _all_ writes are flushed.

Comment: n.b.: In the past, some drives were discovered to be lying about flushing the onboard cache. I'll be charitable and say it was an "incomplete implementation" of the function. I haven't heard about a case for at least ten years, so I assume it's not an issue in any drive we're likely to be using.

Comment: @misha256 Very belated - thank you for the correction. It was only four seconds in very early versions of the NT family, perhaps NT 4 and earlier - I haven't tested to see when the behavior changed.

Comment: If every second, 1/8 of all dirty pages are queued for writing (and the writes finish quickly), then wouldn't it take ***forever*** to write all the dirty pages? If there are no new dirty pages, each second, it would queue fewer pages, and it would stop queuing pages when there are 7 pages left (or 3 pages if rounding is used instead of floor)?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's recommendation is to not turn off write-cache buffer flushing unless the connected device has its own power supply, in order to prevent loss in case of power outage. This is straight from the Disk properties/Policies tab (see image below).

[image: write-cache buffer flushing]

The buffers should flush only on confirmed write, but there are some interoperation issues with a disk's cache. But as far as a power failure, we are talking about a couple of seconds. That is, you won't have data loss unless the power outage happens within two seconds of a write.

If you lose power in the middle of a call to FlushFileBuffers, you could end up with just partial writes, as complete write isn't done before the buffer is fully flushed. There is an index store which points to where the data actually is. This index store is written first.

Comment: To clarify: "Enable write caching on the device" refers to the drive's on-board cache. If enabled, you then have the second option, "Turn off Windows write-cache buffer flushing on the device" - this is where Windows is periodically telling the drive "flush your buffer. Flush your buffer. Flush your buffer..."

Comment: (continued) Neither of these affects either Windows' internal caching, of which there are two types: The file cache (which I refer to as the "reactive" cache) or SuperFetch, which is a "proactive" cache. SuperFetch-cached stuff never has to be written anywhere because it's never modified while it's only in the cache, but the "reactive" cache can be written to, and this is the "cache  flushing" that happens on an eight-second window as described in my answer.