# Disabling "Enable write caching on the device" appears to have no effect with either SSD or HDD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, cache

We are testing how our system (currently running on Windows 7 embedded) will behave if the power is cut to it without warning.   Our PC deliberately does not run on a UPS.

In one test, we created a simple text file in Notepad, added some text, saved the file, then turned the power off a few seconds later, i.e. not a graceful shutdown.

When we powered back on, the changes to the file had NOT been saved.

On further investigation, we noticed that our Crucial MX200 SSD had "Enable write caching on the device" checked.

After *unchecking* that setting, we tried our tests again, assuming that disk-writes would be immediately written, and not cached.

But as before, the changes to the file still weren't stored, if we cut the power a few seconds after 'saving' the file.

Update - we've tested this behaviour using 2 different brands of SSD and an HDD, and the behaviour is the same.  It just looks like write-caching never gets disabled...

Is there anything else that we're missing?

Comment: How are the disks connected? Directly to SATA, or via a SATA-to-USB bridge? I'm pretty sure write caching is for "removable" device classes - e.g. USB and SD type media

Comment: Directly to SATA.    I get your point though - when I've had removable USB devices in previous PCs, I've seen the option of Performance vs Data Integrity, due to this setting.   Thing is, if the write-caching only applies to USB/SD media, then surely Windows can detect this, and just not offer the option in Device Manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we confirmed our issue wasn't specific to one particular brand or type of drive, we suspected it was Windows behaviour, in our case, Windows 7.

After more searching, we found this post:
[How frequently does windows flush the write cache?](https://superuser.com/questions/1196755/how-frequently-does-windows-flush-the-write-cache)

Which confirms that it takes 8 seconds to fully flush Windows internal file cache.

The workaround was to update our source code as indicated here - https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66052/.

While opening our files using `fopen`, we included the Microsoft-specific mode option "c" as the last option, and we used `_flushall()` immediately before calling `fclose()`.